# class number of pure cubic fields and elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

I want to find generators to Mordell Weil group of the Elliptic Curve $y^2=x^3−6321363052$ and class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{6321363052})$. Some suggestions such as algorithm or softwares will be helpful.

Comment: See here for an answer by name_in_caps: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179673/how-to-find-generators-to-mordell-weil-groups-of-elliptic-curves.

Comment: I'm sure he has seen it, since he posted the original question on OF.

Answer (score 0):

You could try SAGE:

```
sage: K.<x> = NumberField(x^3 - 6321363052)
sage: K.class_number()

sage: E = EllipticCurve(QQ,[0,-6321363052])
sage: E.gens()
```

EDIT: One should expect the computations to take a while. These are not easy computations to carry out and patience is key.

Comment: When I tried it with sage it is giving error. Is there any other method to calculate.

Comment: @MKJ What is the error message?

Comment: It is giving runtime error as Unable to compute the rank, hence generators, with certainty (lower bound=1, generators found=[[11688200284997, 18964089155, 6321363049]]).  This could be because Sha(E/Q)[2] is nontrivial.
Try increasing descent_second_limit then trying this command again.